# Получение  названия из ключа в массиве

Tags: массивы

Здраствуйте.

```
$array=array('name1'=>'key1','name2'=>'key2');
```

Знаю, чтобы узнать `key1` нужно `$array['name1']`, но как получить `name1`?
Вопрос простой, но возможно плохо гуглил.

Comment: Вам нужно получить название ключа по значению? Ключ это name1, а значение это key1.

Comment: Чтобы вывести 'key1', нужно echo $array['name1'];
Но как вывести 'name1'?

Comment: наверное, вам [сюда](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). хотя непонятно, что делать с массивом дальше, если вам неизвестны заранее ни ключи, ни их семантика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас немного всё перепутано - получение значения по ключу вы знаете.

Поиск ключа по значению можно сделать так:

```
$key = array_search('key1', $array); // ищет до первого совпадения
```

Можно сделать хуже:

```
$tmp = array_flip($array);
$key = $array['key1']; // при совпадении ключей сохранится последнее значение
```

*А еще возьму и воспользуюсь наводкой, которую дал [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)*

Поиск всех ключей с заданным значением:

```
$keys = array_keys($array, 'key1');
```